Oasis CMIS counting
We need to count some documents by type like this:
SELECT cmis:objectId, type FROM table WHERE userId = '000001'

but Open Oasis CMIS not support count(*) and groupBy.
Is there any smart API usage to handle just counting?
For now only solution looks like to usage pagination based on "hasMoreItems": true,.
Additional info:
We use CMIS binding "browser", Java, Apache Chemistry OPENCMIS.
